# Can PHPStorm autocomplete list numbers

Tags: html, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In HTML pages, I found myself many times writing long lists like this:

```
<ul>
<li><img src="/images/image-1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="/images/image-2.jpg" /></li>
...
<li><img src="/images/image-30.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to make PHPStorm to create this lists? I checked live templates but could not find a way to make this work.

BTW, I know you can use PHP or JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make PHPStorm to create this lists?

**Yes** -- PhpStorm supports **Emmet** (expanding abbreviations) -- just use it.

Documentation: http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Example abbreviation (for your case):

```
ul>li*30>img[src="/images/image-$.jpg"]
```

Just type it (or Copy+Paste) and press TAB (or whatever else expansion key you may set in `Settings | Emmet`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emmet in phpStorm to achieve this.

[Overview](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/26/goodbye-zen-coding-hello-emmet/) - 
[General Emmet Docs](http://docs.emmet.io/)

Comment: You sure can: LazyOne expounded on his answer for an exact example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21414843/24875